# How to send image file directly to server

Tags: java, android, jax-rs

I'm new to android, Im try to send image file directly to my server and .I don't know how to do that. I'm using JAX-RS Restful web service in my server using post method.

Here my code (Android code):

```
File myFile = new File("/path/to/file.png");
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
try {
params.put("image", myFile);
UpdateProfilePicToServer(params);
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {}

private void UpdateProfilePicToServer(RequestParams params) {
    // Show Progress Dialog
    prgDialog.show();
    // Make RESTful webservice call using AsyncHttpClient object
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
  //  client.setTimeout(20000);
      client.post(URL, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            // Hide Progress Dialog
            prgDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                // JSON Object
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(new String(responseBody));
                // When the JSON response has status boolean value assigned with true
                if (obj.getBoolean("status")) {

                    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                // Else display error message
                else {
                    profilePic.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile_placeholder);
                    Toast.makeText(context, obj.getString("msg"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error Occured [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            // Hide Progress Dialog
            prgDialog.dismiss();
            // When Http response code is '404'
            if (statusCode == 404) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            // When Http response code is '500'
            else if (statusCode == 500) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            // When Http response code other than 404, 500
            else {
                Log.d("StatusCode", String.valueOf(statusCode));
                Toast.makeText(context, "Check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Here my web service code(Java):

```
public String post(@FormParam("accId") String accId, @FormParam("image") File image) throws Exception
{
    try {
        Statement chkUserStmt = DataAccess.conn.createStatement();
        String updatequery = "UPDATE ACCOUNT SET PROFILE_PICTURE = LOAD_FILE('" + image+ "') "
                                 + "WHERE ACCOUNT_ID = '" + accId + "'";
        chkUserStmt.executeUpdate(updatequery); 
        chkUserStmt.close();
        return Utility.respJSON("ImageStore ", true, "Success");                
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ImageStore.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }      
    return Utility.respJSON("ImageStore ", false, "Failure");            
}
```

My Logcat:

```
10-26 16:04:38.347 8198-9571/com.h2o W/System.err:   org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
10-26 16:04:38.352 8198-9571/com.h2o W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:582)
10-26 16:04:38.352 8198-9571/com.h2o W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:503)
10-26 16:04:38.352 8198-9571/com.h2o W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:148)
10-26 16:04:38.352 8198-9571/com.h2o W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:179)
10-26 16:04:38.352 8198-9571/com.h2o W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:108)
10-26 16:04:38.352 8198-9571/com.h2o W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
10-26 16:04:38.353 8198-9571/com.h2o W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-26 16:04:38.353 8198-9571/com.h2o W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-26 16:04:38.353 8198-9571/com.h2o W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-26 16:04:38.353 8198-9571/com.h2o W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
10-26 16:04:38.353 8198-9571/com.h2o W/System.err: Caused by: org.apache.http.client.NonRepeatableRequestException: Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity
10-26 16:04:38.353 8198-9571/com.h2o W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:439)
10-26 16:04:38.353 8198-9571/com.h2o W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:580)
```

I don't know where I did wrong.. please anyone help me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See this one.  See the tutorial [Upload Image to server using android](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/)

Comment: In that tutorial, They send encode image but i want to send image file directly

Comment: If you need to send image file directly, you need to use **web sockets** which will act as a **tcp/ip** connection. Then you can write byte stream directly in to the socket. Preferred way is to Base64 encode the image and send it as a HTTP request.